# Emacs regex query replace, space in expression is removed

Tags: regex, emacs

I am trying to replace an erroneous C bracing style in a file with regexes in emacs.

All

```
if (foo)
{
    bar();
}
```

and the likes must become:

```
if (foo) {
    bar();
}
```

**Please** let's not discuss whether it's a good idea to do that, or which bracing style is best. Please.

I am trying to achieve that with emacs' `query-replace-regexp`:

- match "`^Q^J +{`"
- replace with "`SPC{^Q^J`", with `SPC` being an actual space (not showing here on SO)

Somehow, the first character in the string to replace to is not taken into account, and I end up with:

```
if (foo){
    bar();
}
```

(no space before `{`.)

Any idea what is happening, and how I can make sure the space gets there?

Comment: replace "^Q^J *{" with " {"

Comment: Why doesn't it work with `+`? I try to replace any number of space greater than one (ie not `{` that are at column 1). If I use `*`, I would replace the `{` at the start of function definitions.

Comment: I just tried your regexp and replacement and I don't get the effect you observe, i.e., I do get a space between `(foo)` and `{`. P.S.: Why do you re-insert `^Q^J` after the `{` in the replacement? Shouldn't the brace already have a newline following it?

Comment: @Thomas: this is odd. You are correct about the `^Q^J`, and removing it makes the missing space appear. So there is a solution to my actual problem, but I still don't understand why adding `^Q^J` would remove the space.

Comment: It cannot be the reason, and in fact, it works for me fine even when I leave `^Q^J` in (which then produces an empty line as expected).

Comment: Did you try this in an `emacs -Q` instance? Maybe some "clever" mode is messing up your result?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(defun braces-KR-style ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (search-forward-regexp "\n[[:blank:]]*?{" nil t)
    (replace-match " {" nil t))
  )
```